# How many kilometers do I need to walk for my buddy Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

Since the new update, one can select a buddy Pokémon. Walking a certain number of kilometers then yields one candy for that Pokémon.

It seems that the number of kilometers per candy is specific to the Pokémon. How can I know how many kilometers are required for a Pokémon?

Comment: wa?? where's my update?

Comment: @Aequitas Niantec is slowly rolling it out instead of all at once to prevent server load.

Comment: @Rapitor It seems like it's unavailable for IOS users, something to do with the app store approving updates taking a couple of days or something.

Comment: @Aequitas, I read that they may have been holding it back for iOS 10, which comes out today. **is crossing fingers**

Comment: I haven't gotten the update yet on Android 5.1 NA, either.

Comment: I'm really excited for this to come.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Pokemon Go: 1km per Candy Buddy Pokemon**

- Caterpie (and Metapod and Butterfree)
- Weedle (and Kakuna and Beedrill)
- Pidgey (and Pidgeotto and Pidgeot)
- Rattata (and Raticate)
- Spearow (and Fearow)
- Pikachu (and Raichu)
- Clefairy (and Clefable)
- Jigglypuff (and Wigglytuff)
- Zubat (and Golbat)
- Geodude (and Graveler and Golem)
- Magikarp (and Gyarados)

**Pokemon Go: 3km per Candy Buddy Pokemon**

- Bulbasaur (and Ivysaur and Venusaur)
- Charmander (and Charmeleon and Charizard)
- Squirtle (and Wartortle and Blastoise)
- Ekans (and Abrok)
- Sandshrew (and Sandslash)
- Nidoran (F) (and Nidorina and Nidoqueen)
- Nidoran (M) (and Nidorino and Nidoking)
- Vulpix (and Ninetales)
- Oddish (and Gloom and Vileplume)
- Paras (and Parasect)
- Venonat (and Venomoth)
- Diglett (and Dugtrio)
- Meowth (and Persian)
- Psyduck (and Golduck)
- Mankey (and Primeape)
- Growlithe (and Arcanine)
- Poliwag (and Poliwhirl and Poliwrath)
- Abra (and Kadabra and Alakazam)
- Machop (and Machoke and Machamp)
- Bellsprout (and Weepinbell and Victreebel)
- Tentacool (and Tentacruel)
- Ponyta (and Rapidash)
- Slowpoke (and Slowbro)
- Magnemite (and Magneton)
- Farfetch’d
- Doduo (and Dodrio)
- Seel (and Dewgong)
- Grimer (and Muk)
- Shellder (and Cloyster)
- Gastly (and Haunter and Gengar)
- Drowzee (and Hypno)
- Krabby (and Kingler)
- Voltorb (and Electrode)
- Exeggcute (and Exeggutor)
- Cubone (and Marowak)
- Lickitung
- Koffing (and Weezing)
- Rhyhorn (and Rhydon)
- Tangela
- Kangaskhan
- Horsea (and Seadra)
- Goldeen (and Seaking)
- Staryu (and Starmie)
- Tauros
- Porygon
- Ditto

**Pokemon Go: 5km per Candy Buddy Pokemon**

- Onix
- Hitmonlee
- Hitmonchan
- Chansey
- Mr. Mime
- Scyther
- Jynx
- Electabuzz
- Magmar
- Pinsir
- Lapras
- Eevee (and Vaporeon and Jolteon and Flareon)
- Omanyte (and Omastar)
- Kabuto (and Kabutops)
- Aerodactyl
- Snorlax
- Dratini (and Dragonair and Dragonite)

**Pokemon Go: 20km per Candy Buddy Pokemon**

- All Legendary Pokemon

Comment: So basically the same divisions as egg groups.

Comment: @Pyritie Pretty much yeah

Comment: @Pyritie Except for starters it seems.